# How can I retain multilevel columns if I'm merging two panda dataframes in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, merge, multi-level

At my project I initialize an object with an empty pandas dataframe. Within a method of this object I create another dataframe, with a multilevel column. Also I merge the second dataframe with the empty dataframe and I expect that merged dataframe has also a multilevel column, but the multilevel column is converted to a single level column with a tuple of my levels. So how can I retain the multilevel column in my new dataframe?

A minimal, working example:

```
import pandas as pd
tuples = [(u'obs', u'TMP2m')]
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['product', 'variable'])
data = pd.DataFrame()
data1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],columns = col)
data = pd.merge(data, data1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
print data
```

I get this output:

```
+----------------------+
|        |(obs, TMP2m) |
+----------------------+
| 0      |       1     |
| 1      |       2     |
| 2      |       3     |
+----------------------+
```

But I expect this output:

```
+------------------+
| product  |   obs |
+------------------+
| variable | TMP2m |
+------------------+
| 0        |     1 |
| 1        |     2 |
| 2        |     3 |
+------------------+
```

p.s. I'm using Python 2.7.6 and pandas 0.16.0

The corrected mwe:

```
import pandas as pd

class time_series( object ):

    def __init__( self ):
        self.data = pd.DataFrame()

    def add_series ( self, series_data, var ):
        tuples = [(u'obs', var)]
        col = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['product', 'variable'])
        data1 = pd.DataFrame(series_data, columns = col)
        self.data = pd.merge(self.data, data1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you need to merge an empty dataframe with anything, sounds like an overkill...

Overwriting it should be sufficient:

```
tuples = [('product','obs'), ('variable','TMP2m')]
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(tuples)
data1 = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]], columns=col)
print data1

   product   obs
  variable TMP2m
0        0     1
1        1     2
2        2     3

data = pd.DataFrame()
data = data1 # This should be enough to have the end result 
print data

   product   obs
  variable TMP2m
0        0     1
1        1     2
2        2     3
```

But if you must... just replace last line with this:

```
data = data.reindex(columns=data1.columns)
data = pd.merge(data, data1, on=data1.columns.tolist(), how='outer')
print data

   product   obs
  variable TMP2m
0        0     1
1        1     2
2        2     3
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this will work for a single merge, but I want to do the merge every time I call the method. So I think my mwe was wrong (corrected at the end of my first post). 
I think I can work with df.reindex as workaround, but it will be only a workaround, because I thought there will be a parameter within the pd.merge routine to contain the multilevel column name.